# JS Toggle Visibility: How to Hide Already Visible Elements on Click

Tags: javascript, toggle

I'm using Javascript to show / hide elements on a page when I click the links. It works as expected. However, when I click on the links, I want all other visible elements to be hidden. How can I achieve this? Thank you in advance!

Here's my code:

```
**JS**

<script type="text/javascript" async>
<!--
function toggle_visibility(id) {
   var e = document.getElementById(id);
   if(e.style.display == 'block')
      e.style.display = 'none';
   else
      e.style.display = 'block';
}
//-->
</script>


**CSS/HTML**

div {
display:none;
}

<a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('punctuation');">PUNCTUATION</a>
<a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('grammar');">GRAMMAR</a>

<div id="punctuation">
Punctuation stuff
</div>

<div id="grammar">
Grammar stuff
</div>
```

Comment: Loop through all the elements in body, hide them if they aren't already

Comment: You may want to use a class name instead of style attributes. This will allow you to use the `classList.toggle` method.

Answer (score 0):

First set all elements to the display of the item u are toggling. and then set the element you are toggling to the opposite.

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {

   var e = document.getElementById(id);
   var curDisplay = e.style.display;
   el = document.getElementsByClassName('foo');
   el.forEach(function(e){
       // this can be set as 'none' is you want hide instead of toggle
       e.style.display = curDisplay;
   }) 

   if (curDisplay == 'block')
       e.style.display = 'none';
   else
       e.style.display = 'block';
}


<div class="foo" id="punctuation">
Punctuation stuff
</div>

<div class="foo"  id="grammar">
Grammar stuff
</div>
```